# What is the root cause of PyArrow HDFS IO error?

Tags: hdfs, dask, pyarrow

I'm running a Dask-YARN job that dumps a results dictionary into HDFS (code shown in traceback below) using PyArrow's HDFS IO library. However, the job intermittently runs into the error shown below, not every run, only sometimes. I'm unable to determine the root cause of this issue, anyone have any ideas?

```
  File "/extractor.py", line 87, in __call__
    json.dump(results_dict, fp=_UTF8Encoder(f), indent=4)
  File "pyarrow/io.pxi", line 72, in pyarrow.lib.NativeFile.__exit__
  File "pyarrow/io.pxi", line 130, in pyarrow.lib.NativeFile.close
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 87, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: HDFS CloseFile failed, errno: 255 (Unknown error 255) Please check that you are connecting to the correct HDFS RPC port
```

Comment: please list the versions of the libraries involved (dask, pyarrow, fsspec) and show the code you executed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was being cause by duplication of computation of "dask.get" tasks on Delayed objects, which was leading to multiple processes attempting to write to the same file.